# Adding custom behavior to all repositories - does not work

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA and I am trying to add custom behaviour to all repositories as described here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

See my implementation below.

My entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Car extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String model;
    private String manufaturer;

    public Car() {
        this.setId(null);
    }

    public Car(Long id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setManufaturer(String manufaturer) {
        this.manufaturer = manufaturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getManufaturer() {
        return manufaturer;
    }
}
```

My interface declaring custom shared behavior:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    String custom();
}
```

My repository base class - implementation:

```
public class CommonRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CommonRepository<T, ID> {

    public CommonRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }

    public CommonRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
                                EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public String custom() {
        return "CustomValue";
    }

}
```

My factory bean:

```
public class CommonRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends
        JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new CustomRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class CustomRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public CustomRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);

            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            return new CommonRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
            // to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
            return CommonRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

My java configuration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackageClasses = Car.class, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CommonRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@Configuration
class CommonRepositoryConfig {
}
```

And finally my repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CommonRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

My simple unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CommonRepositoryConfig.class)
public class CarRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    CarRepository repository;

    /**
     * Test invocation of custom method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCustomMethod() {

        Car car = new Car();
        car.setManufaturer("ford");

        Car car1 = repository.save(car);

        String customCarValue = repository.custom();
        System.out.println(customCarValue);
        assertNotNull(customCarValue);

    }

}
```

But when I run my unittest I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMapppingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:260)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:63)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:83)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:268)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:51)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
... 43 more
```

All the classes are in the same package.

**EDIT**:
I added a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and other beans as described here:
http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3/
and get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class Car
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaPersistableEntityInformation.<init>(JpaPersistableEntityInformation.java:39)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>(SimpleJpaRepository.java:96)
at CommonRepositoryImpl.<init>(CommonRepositoryImpl.java:15)
at CommonRepositoryFactoryBean$CustomRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(CommonRepositoryFactoryBean.java:37)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:177)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
```

Comment: I wonder if you added the entity class to your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`.